# Получение списока пакетов

Tags: debian, shell

Нужно получить список пакетов, которые соответствуют таким критериям:
1. От этих пакетов не зависят другие пакеты
2. Приоритет этих пакетов не выше стандартного(Standard), тоесть приоритет должен быть один из следуйщих:
Стандартный, Необязательный или Дополнительный
Как это лучше всего сделать?

Comment: 1. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119743/110559 2. http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html

Comment: Большое спасибо